# Unsupported subquery with table in join predicate

Tags: google-bigquery

I am tried to run the next query but the next message appearance "Unsupported subquery with table in join predicate." Do you have some idea? I appreciate your comments.

```
WITH
  D1 AS (
  SELECT
    SETID,
    CUST_ID,
    MAX(EFFDT) AS EFFDT
  FROM
    `g4s-data-reporting.g4s_data.PS_CUST_CREDIT`
  WHERE
    EFFDT <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
  GROUP BY
    1,
    2 ),
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `g4s-data-reporting.g4s_data.PS_CUST_CREDIT` D
  ON
    A.SETID = D.SETID
    AND A.CUST_ID = D.CUST_ID
    AND D.EFFDT = (
    SELECT
      MAX(EFFDT) --select 2
    FROM
      `g4s-data-reporting.g4s_data.PS_CUST_CREDIT` D1
    WHERE
      D1.SETID = D.SETID
      AND D1.CUST_ID = D.CUST_ID
      AND D1.EFFDT <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() )
  WHERE
    B.BUSINESS_UNIT IN ('00001',
      '00048')
    AND B.ITEM_STATUS = 'O'
    AND B.ENTRY_TYPE NOT IN ('AO',
      'CNVBC',
      'MC',
      'OA')
```

Comment: This is one huge query. In order to help the experts answer your question, I suggest that you a) Reduce its size to a minimum that reproduces the issue, and b) format the query for better readability.

Comment: `WITH D1 AS (), LEFT OUTER JOIN ...` makes no sense at all! please double check your question and try to make sure it at least comply with basic syntax

Comment: Always the best approach to solve a SQL Query problem is to break it in parts. As the problem mention that the limit is because of Sub querying, then separate the Queries and run it as different parts. Then pass the result of the Subquery as a second step to the main Query. Also I suggest as Mikhail, to review the Objective of the full Query, I don't fully get the data strategy of the Join. So going simple without to many conditions on the Wheres, until the query runs, then go back to adding conditions.